# Closures vs. classes for encapsulation?

Tags: javascript, class, closures

I'm new to JS (from C++/etc), and it's just occurred to me that closures seem to be a simpler and more convenient way to handle encapsulation than classes. This code seems to give a simple way to handle encapsulation:

```
function addProperty(o) {
   var value;

   o["get"] = function()  { return value; }
   o["set"] = function(v) { value = v; }
}

// create two independent objects which are instances of pseudo-class 'addProperty',
// which each have their own version of a set of local fields, and methods that
// operate on those fields:
var a = {};
addProperty(a);
var b = {};
addProperty(b);
```

If you just want a class to handle encapsulation (in C++, I find this is most of the time), is there any good reason to use a JS class instead of a closure? The code above seems to me to be more intuitive and compact than JS classes. No constructors, prototypes, or excessive use of 'this'. You also get the benefit that you must explicitly declare local fields, instead of hoping that you don't make any typos in your constructor.

### EDIT

Ok, I'll just clarify. Seems like the 'class' word gets some backs up. A "class", to me anyway, is an extension of the type concept, and JS doesn't qualify on that front, but I can do various class-y things with what my book (Flanagan) spends 50 pages calling classes. Sort of.

Anyway, the real question is this: I'm using jQuery tabs on my first web app. I noticed yesterday that this doesn't work, because my JS code doesn't keep any private state for each tab. When I swap between tabs, the dynamic/mouse parts of my code no longer work properly.

So, what's the best way to introduce private state into the app? Most of the code is safe, but everything that handles dynamic behaviour needs some way to encapsulate per-tab local state. With a C++ background, the obvious answer to me is to write a class that defines the dynamic parts of a tab, and to instantiate a new 'tab' object each time a tab is created. What I'm finding it difficult to get my head around is whether JS pseudo-classes actually make any sense here, or whether I should extend the code above.

Just read the module patterns link from Jonathan, and it now seems to me to be that that may be the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JavaScript class. Either that, or I've been doing it wrong these last 6 years.

Comment: IMHO, that's semantics.  They may not be called classes in code, but for all practical purposes, you declare classes and instance them into objects.

Comment: Ok - how about the relative merits of (a) closure, and (b) "the group of language constructs which include prototypes, constructors, and inheritance, whose purposes in other languages include the encapsulation of objects and the methods that operate on those objects", as a general encapsulation mechanism in JavaScript?

Comment: The classic response: [Objects are merely a poor man's closures.  But then again, closures are just a poor man's objects.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg03277.html)

Comment: Since 2019/2020 JavaScript classes are widely supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reasons to avoid closures is overhead.

Your get and set functions are trivially 20x slower than properties. Your closures also have a large memory overhead that is O(N) with the number of instances.

Also note that these encapsulated variables have zero real benefit, they just infer performance penalties.

```
var AddProperty = {
  constructor: function (v) { this._value = v; return this; },
  get: function () { return this._value; },
  set: function (v) { this._value = v; }
};

var a = Object.create(AddProperty).constructor(1);
var b = Object.create(AddProperty).constructor(2);
```

> I noticed yesterday that this doesn't work, because my JS code doesn't keep any private state for each tab.

Your problem is not that you don't have private state, it's that you're using global state.

The easy solution is to have an object per tab (or a "struct" if you prefer) and store state in it.

So all you have to do is define a tab

```
var Tab = {
  constructor: function (...) {
    /* init state */
  },
  doTabStuff: function () { /* some method */ },
  ...
}
```

And then create new tabs when you need them

```
var tab = Object.create(Tab).constructor(...)
```

Comment: Currently `a` and `b` are assigned `undefined`. You might want to enable chaining inside `constructor`.

Comment: @pimvdb I forgot about `return this;`

Comment: +1 - great answer.  I knew closures kept live references to "stuff", but I didn't know they were 20x slower.

Comment: @AdamRackis well a function call is 20x slower then property assignment

Comment: @Raynos - ahhhh.  How silly.  Yeah, I guess the main point here is that (as you said) privacy adds zero benefit in this case.  Colleges convinced a generation of programmers that having "getters" and "setters" is always a good thing.  It seldom is.

Comment: But if I avoid closures, what's left? I'm not really concerned with trivial get/set methods - see my edit above.

Comment: @EML see edit. You just need an object with it's own state for each tab

Comment: @AdamRackis I think that's Java and Java generally likes teaching people that you should have private state and getter/setters for everything even though it's the same as public state.

Answer (score 5):

The benefit of a function for the purposes of encapsulating functionality is that you can use the module pattern:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

The module pattern provides the capability of creating private members and methods, without something with a lot of overhead like ease.js:

http://easejs.org/

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but there are a few things the answers are missing so I figure I'd add to this.

First, as commenters love to point out, there aren't any real classes in javascripts, we just mimic them with closures. Here's what the javascript tutorials call a "class:"

```
function Class1(){
    var privateState='blah';
    this.get=function(){
        return privateState;
    }
}
var myObj=new Class1();
```

Importantly, the `get` method is just a closure. So, this is basically the same as your code. Because closures must reference the environment in which they were created (this is how they can use the private internal state data), they are more costly than just using a public function. So if you have a static method that doesn't require the internal state, you should add it to `Class1` instead by using the `prototype` key word:

```
Class1.prototype.staticMethod=function(){...};
```

This way, the static method can be used through the prototype chain without using up extra memory with unnecessary closures. You could also achieve this with your method by adding static methods outside of your `AddProperty`function.

So, in the end the only difference between a formal javascript "class" and your `AddProperty` function is that when you actually use the class constructor, the class appears in the object's prototype chain, whereas your objects just inherit directly from the generic `object` prototype. You could certainly write code that uses this distinction, but that would probably be bad code.