# Private-like properties in models or views of Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, private

Is it possible to have private properties in a model? Like the locally declared variables in a (constructor) function, not attached to `this`, but declared locally and visible only by whatever is defined in the (constructor)function. 
Example without BB View:

```
function MyView(aModel){

  var $internalInput = $('<input>');

  this.render: function($where){
     $internalInput.val(aModel.get('SomeProperty'));
     $where.append($('<div class="inputWraper">').append($internalInput));
  };
  this.toggleReadonly: function() {
    toggle $internalInputs readonly attribute
  }
  ...
  + Code to bind input.val to some aModel property(ies) and setup events
  ...
}
```

Note that  `internalInput` is not accessible to outside world and `aModel` is also not accessible (through MyView at least).
So if I want to use Backbone.View  to implement the above MyView, how would i do it and keep $internalInput 'private'?

Comment: Note the only thing "private" achieves is making your code slower.

Comment: Can u elaborate please? I just want it for info hiding purposes so tha t I can change it in the future, without fearing someone might depend on it by having used it directly. But if this means slowing the code then it is an issue. Where can i find more info on your claim?

Comment: [Closures have massive overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8729939/419970),  [Private state is expensive but can be done better](http://raynos.org/blog/23/Prototypes-and-private-state). My personal recommendation is use `_foo` for _internal_ properties that are likely to change. Also if someone depends on _internal_ properties it's _their_ problem when your API changes, not your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to achieve private data by passing an IIFE to `extend` when defining your Backbone objects, rather than just a plain object. For example:

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend((function () {
  var foo = "Private data!";

  return {
    bar: function () {
      console.log(foo);
    }
  };
})());
```

Comment: This would give you something more akin to a private static property. If you're looking to emulate private instance properties (like the OP's var-in-constructor technique), you'll be thrown by the shared state this will leave you with.

Comment: Undoubtedly it will work, but is the only/better way to achieve private variables in backbone? This answer speaks a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/16320901/2253756

Answer (score 3):

You'd better off with

```
var Thing = Backbone.Model.extend(
    {
        constructor : function ()
        {
            var _value = "Private data!";

            this.getValue = function ()
            {
                return _value;
            };
            this.setValue = function (value)
            {
                _value = value;
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: so it different use `initialize` and `constructor`?

Comment: Yes, please refer to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118988/whats-the-difference-between-initialize-and-constructor-on-a-backbone-model

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is fun!

```
var Thing = (function () {
    var number_of_things = 0;

    return function (options) {
        var value = "Private data!";

        return new ( Backbone.Model.extend({
            constructor: function constructor () {
              number_of_things += 1;
            },

            getValue: function getValue () {
                return value;
            }
        }) )();
    };
}());
```

I'm a little concerned by the fact that every instance of this "Thing" is also a subclass, in the OOP lingo.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of using [Broserify.js](http://browserify.org/) with Backbone (and really any above medium project) I found the following way to have private vars and functions:

myView.js

```
'use strict';

var config     = require('../config.js'),

    private_var   = 'private variable',
    my_private_fn = function() {
        ...
    };


module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.my_public = 'public variable');

        console.log('This is my' + this.my_public);
        console.log('This is my' + my_private);
    },
});
```

The idea to take here is go with Browserify :P

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is the following:

```
...
initialize:function(properites){            
    // Init the logic with private and public methods/variable
    this.logic.initFirst(this);
    // Use public methods
    this.logic.doSomething();
},  

logic:{         
    initFirst:function(modelOrView){
        // Do not continue if already initiated
        if( this.instance !== undefined ) return;

        // Write all logic here
        this.instance = (function(logic, modelOrView){               
            // Private variables
            var private = "private";                

            // Public methods
            logic.doSomething = function(){
                console.log(private, modelOrView);
            };  

            // Private methods
            function hidden(){

            }

        }(this, modelOrView));  
    }

},
```