# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined when adding model to collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using backbone 1.1.2 with underscore 1.3.3 and JQuery 1.7.1 to create a model that stores 3 values (x,y and z), put this model in a collection and the collection in a view using a modular approach.

Following are my codes:

app.js

```
<code>
requirejs.config({
    paths : {
        app : '/app',
        jquery : ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min"],
        underscore : ["http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min"],
        backbone : ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min"]
    },
    shim : {
        jquery : {
            deps : [],
            exports : '$'
        },
        underscore : {
            deps : [],
            exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
</code>
```

main.js

```
<code>
define(function(require) {

    var DataSet = require('./model/DataModel.js');

    var DataCollection = require('./collection/DataCollection.js');
    var DataView = require('./view/DataViews.js');
});
</code>
```

DataModel.js

```
<code>
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var DataSet = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize : function() { xVal:0; yVal:0; zVal:0;
            alert("at model");
        },

        defaults : {

            xVal : 0,
            yVal : 0,
            zVal : 0
        }
    });

    return DataSet;

});
</code>

DataCollection.js

<code>
    define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', '../model/DataModel.js'],   function($, _, Backbone, DataSet) {

    var DataSetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : DataSet,

        view : null,

        initialize : function() {

        },

        constructor : function() {
            console.log('Book\'s constructor had been called');
        }
    });

    return DataSetCollection;

});
</code>
```

DataView.js

```
<code>
    define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', '../collection/DataCollection.js', '../model/DataModel.js'], function($,   _, Backbone, DataCollection, DataSet) {
      //  ... ,  /collection/DataCollection.js
        DataView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName : 'li',

        events : {
            'click #add-input' : 'getAxisValues',
        },

        initialize : function() {
            alert("Initializing View");
            //this.cars = new CarsCollection;
            this.dataCollection = new DataCollection;
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },

        getAxisValues : function() {

            /*
            var xVal = $('#inputX').val();
            var yVal = $('#inputY').val();
            var zVal = $('#inputZ').val();*/

            //adding random values for now for testing
            var dataSet = new DataSet({
                xVal : 4,
                yVal : 5,
                zVal : 6
            });
            alert("Adding values to collection " + dataSet.cid);
            this.dataCollection.push(dataSet);
        },

        render : function(model) {
            alert("Rendering View");

        }
    });
    var view = new DataView({
        el : '#FirstShow'
    });
    return view;
    });
</code>
```

[image: Project Structure]

The Router.js file is empty as of now and will be used later in the project.

The error that I'm getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '[object Object]' of undefined                       backbone.js:806 
i.extend.get                            backbone.js:694 
i.extend.set                            backbone.js:638 
i.extend.add                            backbone.js:776 
i.extend.push                           DataViews.js:32 
Backbone.View.extend.getAxisValues      jquery.min.js:3 
f.event.dispatch                        jquery.min.js:3 
f.event.add.h.handle.i                  jquery.min.js:3
```

In my code, the error is on the following line:

this.dataCollection.push(dataSet);

I had also tried the following earlier

this.dataCollection.add(dataSet);

Thanks!

Comment: I was using backbone 0.9.2 earlier and the error was so:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c4' of undefined

It started with c1, then c2 and so on every time I clicked the add-input button and a new model was created.

After using the latest version of backbone the error is as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are some issues
1) you are just creating only one model out of three points.
 
2) you aren't really initalizing the collection. the code should be like this

```
this.dataCollection = new DataCollection();
```

so if you want to add three models to collection just write

```
 this.dataCollection = new DataCollection([{xVal : 4},{yVal : 5},{zVal : 6,}])
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it's still not working. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: Are you getting the same error?, provide a fiddle it will be easy.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to figure out a workaround- not exactly a solution. I'll post a fiddle link, just give me sometime to figure out this alternative approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message. Although my case is not exactly the same with this one, it might be useful to put my solution here.

My solution is to use the `initialize` rather than the `constructor`, avoiding adding models to an array or checking whether a model exists in that array which is undefined at that time.

Here's their differences: [What's the difference between initialize and constructor on a backbone model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118988/whats-the-difference-between-initialize-and-constructor-on-a-backbone-model)