# Backbone model: initialize vs. constructor

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, constructor, model, initialization

Reading through the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend), I see that you can replace the constructor for Backbone's extend on a model class. But what's the difference between doing this vs. doing it on the initialize method? Aren't both called when you use `new`?

```
var Library = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    this.books = new Books();
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  parse: function(data, options) {
    this.books.reset(data.books);
    return data.library;
  }
});
```

vs.

```
var Library = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.books = new Books();
    Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  parse: function(data, options) {
    this.books.reset(data.books);
    return data.library;
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between initialize and constructor on a backbone model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118988/whats-the-difference-between-initialize-and-constructor-on-a-backbone-model)

Answer (score 2):

"**constructor**" runs before Backbone sets up the structure.
"**initialize**" is called inside the structure's constructor function.

In other words if you need to add anything to the object before Backbone sets up the structure you might want to use "**constructor**". If you need to add something to your object after that Backbone sets up the structure you can use "**initialize**".

From: [https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/720](http://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/720)