# Declaring variables on a backbone model without setting defaults

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just starting out with backbone.js and I'm looking for a way of declaring fields on a model without having to provide defaults. It's really just for reference, so that when I start creating instances, I can see what fields I need to initialize.

With something like java I'd write

```
public class CartLine{
    StockItem stockItem;
    int quantity;

    public int getPrice(){
        return stockItem.getPrice() * quantity;
    }

    public int getStockID(){
        //
    }
}
```

However with backbone models, I'm referencing the fields in my method's but I'm not actually declaring them - It looks like I could easily create a `CartLine` object that doesn't contain a `stockItem` attribute or a `quantity` attribute. It feels strange not to mention the fields when I declare the object. Particularly as the object is supposed to represent an entity on the server.

```
var CartLine = Backbone.Model.extend({

  getStockID: function(){
    return this.stockItem.id;
  },

  getTotalPrice: function() {
    return this.quantity * this.StockItem.get('price');
  }
});
```

I guess I can add some sort of reference by using validate -

```
CartLine.validate = function(attrs){
  if (!(attrs.stockItem instanceof StockItem)){
    return "No Valid StockItem set";
  }
  if (typeof attrs.quantity !== 'number'){
    return "No quantity set";
  }
}
```

But my question is - am I missing something? Is there an established pattern for this?

Comment: Jsdoc/comments? That's what I use if I don't just set a default value of `null`.

Comment: Models save URL for a given resource, and you construct your request data as you want. Why do you want to declare variables without defaults? Anyway you could declare variables like declaring private or public variables inside a javascript "class"

Answer (score 3):

The `defaults` are really for "fields" or data that is transferred back and forth from the server as part of the json.

If you just want to create some member variables as part of the Model, which are proprietary and not going to be sent back and forth to the server, then you can declare them a) on the object itself or b) in the [initialize](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) method (called during construction), and they can be passed in as part of opts:

```
var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({

    widgetCount: 0,

    defaults: {
        id: null,
        name: null
    }

    initialize: function(attr, opts) {
       // attr contains the "fields" set on the model
       // opts contains anything passed in after attr
       // so we can do things like this
       if( opts && opts.widgetCount ) {
          this.widgetCount = opts.widgetCount;
       }
    }
});

var widget = new Widget({name: 'the blue one'}, {widgetCount: 20});
```

Keep in mind that if you declare objects or arrays on the class, they are essentially constants and changing them will modify all instances:

```
var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({

    someOpts: { one: 1, two: 2},

    initialize: function(attr, opts) {
       // this is probably not going to do what you want because it will
       // modify `someOpts` for all Widget instances.
       this.someOpts.one = opts.one; 
    }
});
```